# Relationships between threads (tasks)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I know that there is no possibilty to distinguish any relationship between threads in the System.Thread model, but is it also not possible in the Task(Task) model?. I would like to profile a multithreaded application, the last thing I would like to do, is passing some kind of context to all my methods and threads. I would appreciate any ideas. What I would like to accomplish is similar to:

1. ThreadMain -750ms (capture method calls)

   - Thread1 - 300ms (capture method calls)

     - Thread11 - 99ms (capture method calls)
     - Thread12 - 20ms (capture method calls)
   - Thread1 - 540ms (capture method calls)

     - Thread21 - 90ms (capture method calls)
     - Thread22 - 60ms (capture method calls)

I have an good idea of capturing the execution time using Postsharp, but I would like to find out the relationship of the parent/child threads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably name the threads in a naming convention of `NewThreadName.CreatedByThreadName` and use the [System.Diagnostics.Process.Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to find the threads associated with the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing, a thread is a thread - it doesn't have any notion of a "parent" or "child" threads.